# Converting Python Programs into Assembly IEEE 694

Tags: python, assembly

Does it exist any tool for converting Python programs or code source files into assembly IEEE 694?
The bytecode generated must work on a IEEE 694 simulator?

Answer (score 4):

Bsides Nuitkla, there is also [cython](http://cython.org) - which can translate Python code to a C file, from which you can compile to assembly source.

And if you want it for the speed of the native code, them, I'd suggest going for [pypy](http://pypy.org) - the Python interpreter written in Python, which features jit (just in time code translation) to x86_64 native code.

Also of interest might be [corepy](http://www.corepy.org), which allows you to enter Assembly instructions inline from within Python code - so that you can have a Python program (running as a .py source, no compilation needed) that makes use of advanced CPU architectures such as sse3 and ss4 (not shure if it supports avx yet), and other architectures such as IBM Cell processor (in unlocked  Playstation 3s)

Comment: [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/blog/) translates Python to C++ if you want another option. You also might want to mention with Cython you also still need libpython.